# Laravel - company logo display got distorted in sub-menus

Tags: html, laravel

In my Laravel-5.8 application, I tried to load the company Logo from a folder into the header of the page:

```html
<a href="{{ route('home') }}" class="brand-link logo-switch navbar-dark bg-gray-light">
  <img src="public/storage/myLogo.png" alt="MyApp" class="brand-image-xl logo-xs">
  <img src="public/storage/myLogo.png" alt="MyApp" class="brand-image-xs logo-xl" style="left: 12px">
</a>
```

I called it this way:

```
@include('layouts.partials.brand-logo')
```

I observed that on the main menu, the image appear well, but on the sun-menus it displays "MyApp". That is, alt

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Where does your image exists ? public folder ?
can you provide a path ?

Comment: @KhalidKhan - This is the path:    public/storage/myLogo.png

Comment: check the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your path like this to access files from public folder

```
<a href="{{ route('home') }}" class="brand-link logo-switch navbar-dark bg-gray-light">
  <img src="{{asset('storage/myLogo.png')}}" alt="MyApp" class="brand-image-xl logo-xs">
  <img src="{{asset('storage/myLogo.png')}}" alt="MyApp" class="brand-image-xs logo-xl" style="left: 12px">
</a>
```